# How do I take a 1D numpy array and turn it into a DF with specific names

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running an image through an auto encoder to get a 1D vector back with size `(224, )`.  I want to take that 1D vector and transpose it to `(, 224)` and put a column name prefix like `image_0, image_1....image_224`.   How do I do that?

I've tried the following:

```
import numpy as np()

test = np.zeros(224,)

test = test.transpose()
```

But that leaves the shape as is.  I later read in the docs that `.transpose` has no effect on a 1D array.

Is there an easy/clean way to do this?

Comment: What is the real shape of your "vector"  - (224,1) ?

Comment: Yes (224,1). Maybe numpy series is the correct terminology.

Comment: `(244,)` is a Python tuple with on element.  The comma is needed to distinguish it from `(244)` where the () are just grouping elements.  `(,244)` is bad syntax.  You create a column vector by adding a trailing dimension, to make shape `(244,1)`.  `np.transpose`  does not do that (it switches existing dimensions).

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(vector.reshape(1, -1).add_prefix('image_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand you want to do something like this:

```py
test = np.zeros(224,)
df = pd.DataFrame(test, index=[f"image{int(i)}" for i in range(len(test))])
```

Comment: almost!  just add `.transpose()` on the back of your second line and it gives me what I want.  I couldn't get there without you. Thanks!